# How to Truncate string with toggle in Ionic 5

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

How can I truncate my paragraph to only show a certain amount of words and the have a "show more" link that opens up the rest of the paragraph in the same page?

In my page.ts file I have an array filled with this code:

```
slides = [
  { 
    paragraph:'a very long long long long paragraph '

  },
  {

    paragraph:'very long long long long paragraph'
  },
  {

    paragraph:'very long long long long paragraph'
  }
];
```

In my HTML file I have this code to show it:

```
<ion-slides [options]="slideOpts" pager="true">
  <ion-slide *ngFor="let slide of slides">
 <div>
  <ion-card> 
  <ion-card-content>
   <br>
    <h4> {{ slide.paragraph }} </h4>

  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
</div>

  </ion-slide>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use css trick to resolve this issue

```
.customStyle {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis; 
}

<h4 class="customStyle"> abc... </h4>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! but how do you get it to show the rest of the words?

Comment: `.customStyle:active {
  overflow: visible;
}`

`.customStyle:hover {
  overflow: visible;
}`

Comment: choose 1 and add to style

Answer (score 0):

You could use this library [@yellowspot/ng-truncate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@yellowspot/ng-truncate)

Then, in your html:

```
<p *ngIf="isFull[i] === true">{{slide.paragraph}} <span (click)="toggleMore(i)">.. see less</span></p>
<p *ngIf="isFull[i] === false">{{slide.paragraph | truncate :100: "..."}} <span *ngIf="slide.paragraph.length > 100" (click)="toggleMore(i)">see more</span></p>
```

In .ts file:

```
getData(){
    for(let i=0; i<this.slides.length; i++){
      this.isFull.push(false);
    }
}

toggleMore(i){
  this.isFull[i] = !this.isFull[i];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the input! however, after I put this code in, it didnt want to open my page anymore.

Comment: is there any error in the chrome debugging? and don't just copy and paste the code as it is, anyway you can see working example in tab 2 here https://ionic-v4-angular-tabs-odamse.stackblitz.io

Comment: I didnt just paste it as it is. Thank you, i'll check it out!